# How do I concatenate 0s and 1s into a new define with the preprocessor (combine several bit defines to one Byte define)?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Currently, we use a structure like the following in a configuration header file to define if a specific feature is supported by this firmware and hardware revision or not:

```
#define FEATURE_BYTE_00 0b11110011
//                        |||||||| 
//                        |||||||FEATURE0
//                        ||||||FEATURE1
//                        |||||FEATURE2
//                        ||||FEATURE3
//                        |||FEATURE4
//                        ||FEATURE5
//                        |FEATURE6
//                        FEATURE7
```

Depending on the defines, some #ifdef are used to compile this or that function into the binary.
But this is pretty nasty (especially because some of the feature bit defines will be depending on some other defines in the future) and I would like to change it so that I define each feature bit separately and then concatenate them to the resulting feature byte:

```
#define FEATURE0 1
#define FEATURE1 1
#define FEATURE2 0
#define FEATURE3 0
#define FEATURE4 1
#define FEATURE5 1
#define FEATURE6 1
#define FEATURE7 1
```

But how do I concatenate these to the feature byte? Unfortunately, the preprocessor is not able to understand the typical syntax you would use for the compiler. I also tried the concatenation tool, but that for some reason does not work as well. As I understand it, it can only be used for strings:

```
#define FEATURE_BYTE_00     (FEATURE7 << 7) || (FEATURE6 << 6) ...         // Not possible 
#define FEATURE_BYTE_00     FEATURE7 ## FEATURE6                           // Also not possible
```

In the second case I get the following error:

```
error: ‘FEATUR7FEATURE6’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

It seems like the preprocessor is simply removing the ## with the surrounding whitespaces?

What would be a good way to do this? I really would like to do this with the preprocessor instead of using c syntax and creating variables.

Comment: The real issue here is your statement "the preprocessor is not able to understand the typical syntax you would use for the compiler" while using the wrong syntax (`||` instead of `|`). So this turns into multiple questions (proper OR-ing of bits, proper use of `##`, proper use of feature flags). Please pick one.

Comment: `#define FEATURE_BYTE_00     (FEATURE7 << 7) || (FEATURE6 << 6) ...         // Not possible `. Why not?

Comment: Whoa, that really is embarrassing ;/ Just messed up the bit operator... And I just thought the prepocessor could not do that! I give my honest apologies for that long unnecessary post...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`||` is not binary `OR` only the logical `OR`.

```
#define FEATURE0 1
#define FEATURE1 1
#define FEATURE2 0
#define FEATURE3 0
#define FEATURE4 1
#define FEATURE5 1
#define FEATURE6 1
#define FEATURE7 1

#define MAKEBYTE(b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7) \
    ( ((b0) << 0) | ((b1) << 1) | ((b2) << 2) | ((b3) << 3) | \
      ((b4) << 4) | ((b5) << 5) | ((b6) << 6) | ((b7) << 7) )


#define GETFEAT() MAKEBYTE(FEATURE0,  FEATURE1, FEATURE2,  FEATURE3, \
    FEATURE4,  FEATURE5, FEATURE6,  FEATURE7)

int main(void)
{
    printf("%x\n", GETFEAT());
}
```